# Getting contact picture on HTC Hero

Tags: android, contacts

So I just recently wrote a class that can get me the contact pictures from all versions of Android, ranging from 1.5 to 2.1 However, it does not work for HTC Hero. Can anyone help me getting the pictures from HTCs crappy contacts-app?

Comment: does it work with other devices? HTC's sense has caused serious problems with Android development here with me, on Vanilla Android things work perfectly but once I try it on anything with HTC sense on it I come across certain bugs on certain builds. I have contacted HTC about these and provided logs to them so hopefully future builds are more stable

Comment: It's not an answer, but ... ;]
If you have access to Hero maybe try to query content resolver with null projection (second argument of ContentResolver.query method) and check in debugger if there is something that looks like picture.

Comment: Odd. I have an app that looks up contacts and displays their contact icon; it works fine on every device I've tested on, including HTC Hero (OS 1.5).. it's just using the standard contacts content provider..